# How to use v-if, v-else inside of v-for properly in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.id">
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ box.name }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.id" class="line">
            <div
              v-if="
                matchingdata.some(
                  (m) => m.boxid == box.boxid && m.paintid == paint.paintid
                )
              "
            >
              <StatusComponent
                :box="box"
                :paint="paint"
                :matchingdata="matchingdata"
              />
            </div>
            <!-- <div v-else>no data found</div> -->
          </div>
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

When i click of each checkbox, i am loading relevant data from box,paint array. by checking in matchingdata. Array.

Now, i want to show like, if no data found onclick of checkbox, i want to display a message as "no data found"

Issue with the below code is, if i place v-if at top and v-for and v-else data at the last then only few data is displaying

Comment: Can you use something like `boxes.length === 0` or `paints.length === 0` to check if there is any data? If there is no data there will be no loop anyway, so you have to check from outside.

Comment: But only issue is after i replace, my code like in codesandbox, i am getting error in console as [Vue warn]: Property or method "paint" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See:

Comment: I can see the "no data found" messages now, yes. But why repeat that message so many times?

Comment: I am thinking that because it is inside of loop. so it is printing multiple times. Any possible solution for that ?

Comment: I understand - you can [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70956155/10441671) for my idea. The key is using `paints.find()` to filter all paints before doing the loop. Haven't tested if it's working when there is data there... maybe you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `matchingdata.some()` again

You can use `matchingdata.some()` in a `v-if` above the `v-for` loop, which checks if any of the paints can be found.
Put a `v-else` at the bottom with your text.

See fix below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.id">
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ box.name }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <template v-if="
              matchingdata.some(
                (m) => m.boxid == box.boxid && paints.find( (paint) => m.paintid == paint.paintid )
              )
            "
          >
            <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.id" class="line">
              <div
                v-if="
                  matchingdata.some(
                    (m) => m.boxid == box.boxid && m.paintid == paint.paintid
                  )
                "
              >
                <StatusComponent
                  :box="box"
                  :paint="paint"
                  :matchingdata="matchingdata"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
          <div v-else>no data found</div>
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I pasted this into your code sandbox and it made the message only appear once per box.

The relevant piece is checking all paints beforehand with `paints.find`:

```js
matchingdata.some(
  (m) => m.boxid == box.boxid && paints.find( (paint) => m.paintid == paint.paintid )
)
```

Documentation:

- [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

The `v-for` is rendering for each 'box' in 'boxes', so for each box you should get a:

```
<BaseAccordian>
  <template v-slot:title>{{ box.name }}</template>
  <template v-slot:content>
    <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.id" class="line">
 {...}
    </div>
  </template>
</BaseAccordian>
```

And for each paint in paints, this should render a div for each paint inside of every box.

The `v-if` and `v-else-if` and `v-else` will render their blocks conditionally on the predicates contained within them. I'm not sure where the array `matchingdata` comes from in your example, but if it contains an element that has the properties `boxid` and `paintid` that match `box.boxid` and `paint.paintid` then the predicate of `matchingdata.some((m) => m.boxid == box.boxid && m.paintid == paint.paintid)` will have been met and the associated div will be rendered; otherwise, the 'v-else' div will be rendered (if it were uncommented).

Your code will loop through each box in boxes, and for each box it will loop through each paint in paints to find an element in matchingdata that looks something like:

```js
{
  boxid: ...,
  paintid: ...,
  ...,
}
```

The v-for and (v-if, v-else-if, v-else) blocks are not connected to each other. v-for represents a loop over which you will render an element for every item in the list. The v-if blocks will conditionally render elements to the page according to the predicates you define.

v-if, v-else-if, and v-else have to appear right after each other to be counted in the same logical block.